Estimate security parameter $n$ for Ajtai commitment
Let $x$ be a binary string of length $m \approx 2^{20}$, $A_{n \times m}$ be a random matrix with entries independently and uniformly drawn from $\mathbb{Z}^*_{q}$, and $q$ be a $128$-bit prime number. The Ajtai commitment of $x$ is $$c = Ax \mod q.$$
According to Micciancio and Regev, to achieve $100$ bit security, one should choose a $n$ such that
$$
2^{2\sqrt{n \lg{q} \lg{\delta}}} \gt 2^{100},
$$ where $\delta \le 1.01$.
This gives an estimiate of $n$ as $$n \ge 1361.$$
My questions are :

Is this estimate correct?
$1361$ times blowup seems to be a lot, think about it: one has to generate $ 1361 \times m$ random numbers to create $A$. Is this what people do in practice?
Are there any schemes that require a significantly smaller number of randomness (say instead of $1361 \times m$ just $1 \times m$)? Or am I asking for too much?


Regarding #2, it is highly likely that people instead use commitment schemes based on structured lattice assumptions in practice. See for example this, though I imagine there is more modern work. Also, this is perhaps a naive question, but why don't you hash $x$ and then commit to that hash?

Mark, thanks for pointing out the paper. The reason for not hashing $x$ is that direct (naive) Ajtai commitment is homomorphic.

In the cited paper, $2^{2\sqrt{n \log q \log \delta}}$ is not computational cost; it's the best vector length you can expect to find in a $n$-dimensional $q$-ary lattice with the best choice of $m$. This means that the shortest vector you can find with $n=1363$, regardless of computational cost, is enormous; it's even enormous at $n=16$. The best attack here is, presumably, the combinatorial one as described in Section 4.1. The requirement here is that short vectors have $L_\infty$ norm $\le 1$.

@SamuelNeves. Thanks, so $2^{2\sqrt{n\lg{q} \lg{\delta}}}$ is the length of the best vector one can find, and for my case, since each entry of $x$ is 0-1, to achieve $100$ bit security, I only need to guarantee the length > 100, not $2^{100}$!! Is it right?

@Jason what type of homomorphism do you need? Precisely describing that could plausibly lead to a suggestion of a much more efficient scheme.
